# Is multiple figcaption semantically correct?

Tags: html

From the [docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element), figcaption can be used:

> As the first or last child of a figure element.

But I didn't find anywhere stating that we can use both (as first and last child). Thus, using the following would be correct?

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Caption one</figcaption>
  <img src="path.jpg" alt="image" />
  <figcaption>Caption two</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I'm concerned about it because how will search engine think about it?

Comment: See https://github.com/w3c/html/pull/179#issuecomment-211366505 for why only one figcaption is allowed in a figure. It also recommends nesting figure elements to achieve a caption both below and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand about the caption is:

It should be used only once. Just simplifying an answer to the question will refine this:

What's your name?

If you answer to the asker stating multiple (or just two) names: Brad, Peter. One is your pet name and another is your calling name. The opponent will be in confusion and you'll also get confusion sometime when s/he calls you. So far so good, just using the one name is perfect to anyone. And the figcaption is similar to the search engine.

Thus, if you think **Caption one** is more important, then you can use it in first place:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Caption one</figcaption>
  <img src="path.jpg" alt="image" />
  <p>Caption two</p><!-- Less important -->
</figure>
```

Or, if you think **Caption two** is more important, then you use it in last place:

```
<figure>
  <p>Caption one</p>
  <img src="path.jpg" alt="image" />
  <figcaption>Caption two</figcaption><!-- More important -->
</figure>
```

You can use any other tag instead of `p` what you think is good. But I prefer here to use `p` tag because caption is more like a paragraph. Use any header tag if your caption is more like a heading.

So, this rule will not violate the standard of html5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. It's not likely that a bot will iterate over figcaptions. It would probably be better to add a more elements in the figcaption. Maybe an `h3` and a `p` then position them.

```
img { 
  position: relative;
}
img figcaption h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```